# Sql Server Back Up

Tags: sql-server, database, database-scripts

I'm using the below to backup a db from a SQL job. Can someone tell me how to add the current date to the output filename? Preferably in YYYYMMDD format.

Comment: what syntax are you using to backup your db?

Comment: `getdate()` gives you the current date. `convert()` will convert it to the format that you required. it is not that difficult. Give it a try

Comment: Where is "below"?